# CakePHP - spitting out XML for webservice

Tags: cakephp

What is the best way to spit out XML for webservice in CakePHP?

I have it like the following but it's displaying an empty page.

Sample call /service/config.xml

In Controller

```
var $helpers = array('Xml');    

function config() {
    $this->autoRender = false;
    $obj = array("response" => array("config" => array(...)));

    $objXmlHelper = new XmlHelper();
    $objXml = $objXmlHelper->header();
    $objXml .= $objXmlHelper->serilize($obj);
    echo $objXml;
}
```

That gives empty page. However, if I echo json_encode($obj); that actually prints out json.

Thanks,
Tee

Answer (score 0):

You probably have an error in your code. My guess is you are not including the XML helper.

Check you CakePHP (app/tmp/logs/) and PHP logs. In addition you may need to set the `DEBUG` flag to a higher level ( i.e. > 0).

I'd also recommend considering moving such things to a model. Web Services are typically data access layers and that belongs in the Model.